# A space below view controller that is embed in a navigation controller which is embed in a ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a `UITabbarController` at the very beginning of my navigation. There is 4 tabs which are referred to 4 different `storyboards`.

In one of the storyboards the starting point is a `UINavigationController` which is the `root` of a `viewcontroller`. In that `viewcontroller` there is 2 `containerviews`. One is for `topbar` and the other one is for my below contents for further navigation. Now, the below `containerview`'s `viewcontroller` is embed in a `navigationcontroller` for navigation purpose. Now when I am running my project I am seeing a space below my first view controller that is embed to that below container view with a navigation controller.

I am attaching screenshot for better understanding of my problem.

This is the first controller:

[image]

Now this is one of the four tabs:
[image]

Now what I am getting as output is:

[image]

> P.S: I have not written any codes for anything untill now.

Comment: did you apply constraint to containerView ?

Comment: try this :  Select the viewController > Deselect "Adjust scroll bar insets"

Comment: yeah I have applied constraints in containerView.

Comment: Try to turning on Extended Egdes -> Under OpaqueBars checkbox on view controller with container view:

Comment: OMG! It solved my problem. You're awesome. Please delete this comment and give it as a answer I'll accept it. Please elaborate there what this actually does. @KKRocks

Answer (score 0):

Try to turning on **Extended Egdes** > **Under OpaqueBars** checkbox on view controller with container view.

Basically, with this property you set which sides of your view can be extended to cover the whole screen

> This property is applied only to view controllers that are embedded in
>   a container such as UINavigationController. The window’s root view
>   controller does not react to this property.

Comment: Please elaborate what it is actually does.

Comment: I can't. That was actually an xcode issue or something. I deleted everything and redesigned, and everything went absolutely fine without any issues.

Comment: then delete this question if there is no any problem .